# Multiple/Optional EndNode Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Current scenario:

User is able to have a Car and a Motorcycle, so a user could have 1 relation [:OWNS] :Car and another to :Motorcycle. It is also possible for the user to have neither or just one of them.

```
U->C & U->M
U->C 
U
```

Current relationship entity:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "OWNS")                      
public class Owns {

@GraphId                                    
Long relationshipId;                            

private int price;

@StartNode                          
Car car;                                

@EndNode                                    
Motorcycle motor;
}
```

How do I set a user to have just one of them? because I get error that an EndNode cannot be null, which understandable at this point. is there a way to make another endNode optional?

Thanks

Comment: When do you run into a problem? You could have a Vehicle superclass perhaps.

Comment: Actually when there's a case where a user just owns a car, it gave me "EndNode cannot be null" Having a superclass would solved it, I was just wondering if there's another way to do it. Thanks @MichaelHunger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a misunderstanding of the @RelationshipEntity? 
A relationship entity is simply a relationship with properties between two nodes.

```
@StartNode                          
Car car;                                

@EndNode                                    
Motorcycle motor;
```

is saying a Car OWNS a Motorcycle.

What you want instead is a User that owns either a Car or Motorcyle, so if you have a superclass `Vehicle` as suggested by Michael, then you would have the following:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "OWNS")                      
public class Owns {

@GraphId                                    
Long relationshipId;                            

private int price;

@StartNode                          
User user;                                

@EndNode                                    
Vehicle vehicle;
}
```

User would have:

```
@Relationship(type="OWNS")
Set<Owns> vehiclesOwned;
```

and this set can have zero or one or many vehicles in it.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up having a superclass.